# Java hashed lock table

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

Is there a struct or lib in java that's meant to be used as "hash table for locks"?

I am storing a large array of hashes that could be accessed by multiple threads. I want to sync on a replace operation on this array. Locking the index itself doesn't work because I'm using an array of primitives. I don't want to store an equally long set of Objects() due to the number of elements I would need. Instead I want to downsize my hash and lock based on that.

I'm doing a update-replace conditional on the previous value, not an add, so that rules out some concurrent libs in the jdk.

Below is my attempt at an implementation:

```
  private final Object[] locks = new Object[256];
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      locks[i] = new Object();
    }
  }

  final static int p = 64;
  byte[] hashTable = new byte[1 << p];
  int populatedCount = 0;

  public void add(String s, int i) {
    int h = GetHash(s);
    int hashBucket = h >>> (32 - p);
    int lockHash = h & 0xFF;
    int oldValue;
    synchronized (locks[lockHash]) {
      oldValue = this.hashTable[hashBucket];
      this.hashTable[hashBucket] = (byte) Math.max(this.hashTable[hashBucket], i);
    }
    if (oldValue == 0) {
      this.populatedCount++;
    }
  }
```

What I really need is a sparse concurrent primitive array...

Comment: Is the `lockHash` value guaranteed to be within the range 0-254?

Comment: 254? it will be 0-255

Comment: If it ranges to 255, your locks array will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: no, seems like locks[] should range from 0-255

Comment: Your locks array is declared to contain 255 elements, element index 255 is invalid and out of bounds. Perhaps you meant to declare locks to 256 elements?

Comment: Concurrent primitive array: JDK's `AtomicIntegerArray`. Won't it suit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

If understood corrctly, you need to atomically get and replace operations for a primitive array (here: an int[]). Correct?

If so, you should read about [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html). This is a class that exactly provides these atomic operations. You could make an AtomicInteger[].

But - while exploring the Java API - a better solution can be found: [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html). An object of this class holds an int[] in one of its fields **and** it provides atomic operations on its values.

---

EDIT

Hmmm ... The requirement to first do a calculation (maximum in this case) while holding the lock seems to be a bit tricky.

The following subclass might do the trick:

```
public class MyAtomicIntegerArray extends AtomicIntegerArray {
    // constructors (see also class AtomicIntegerArray)

    public int setIfGreater(int index, int value) {
        while(true) {
            int oldValue = get(index);
            int newValue = Math.max(value, oldValue);
            if(compareAndSet(index, oldValue, newValue))
                return oldValue;
        }
    }
}
```

The `while(true)` is needed, because the `compareAndSet` method might return `false` if another thread updated the value in the meantime. In that case, we need to calculate again.

Afterwards you use this class and this method in your code:

```
private static final ARRAY_SIZE = ...;

private final MyAtomicIntegerArray hashTable = new MyAtomicIntegerArray(ARRAY_SIZE);

public void add(String s, int i) {
    int h = GetHash(s);
    int hashBucket = h >>> (32 - p);
    int oldValue = hashTable.setIfGreater(hashBucket, i);
    if (oldValue == 0) {
        this.populatedCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: not sure-- I believe those autobox into Object, and I need to save as much memory as I can, and none of those support the replace/max operation I need. also technically I'm storing byte, not int

Comment: An AtomicInteger internally uses an int field. No boxing is involved. But an AtomicInteger[] might have too much objects. An AtomicIntegerArray seems quite right, as this internally uses an int[] (as you also do in your code snippet). Seems like this can be used. If not, maybe I did not understand your requirement. Maybe you can update it?

Comment: I need to synchronously get the old value, and update it if it's smaller than an input var. `oldValue = this.hashTable[hashBucket]; this.hashTable[hashBucket] = (byte) Math.max(this.hashTable[hashBucket], i);`

Comment: Even if it were autoboxing that wouldn’t raise memory consumption as all wrapper values in the `byte` range are represented by canonical objects. By the way if this `add` method is invoked by multiple threads you have to make the updates to `this.populatedCount` thread-safe as well. I’d recommend an `AtomicInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this solution is more of a hack and only works if your integer key is within the range 0-255/-128 to 127.

You discussed how you cannot synchronize on your primitive key simply because its primitive. Why not convert it to a object then?

Take your `lastHash` value and apply the `Integer.valueOf()` method on it to obtain a Integer object then synchronize the Integer object itself as such:

```
public void add(String s, int i) {
    int h = GetHash(s);
    int hashBucket = h >>> (32 - p);
    int lockHash = h & 0xFF;
    int oldValue;
    //Subtract 128 to move the range of values into the cached range of -128 to 127.
    Integer lockVal = Integer.valueOf(lockHash - 128);

    synchronized (lockVal) {
        oldValue = this.hashTable[hashBucket];
        this.hashTable[hashBucket] = (byte) Math.max(this.hashTable[hashBucket], i);
    }
    if (oldValue == 0) {
        this.populatedCount++;
    }
}
```

The Integer object returns for numbers from -128 to 127 will always be the same due to caching as defined in the Integer.valueOf() method shown here:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

In this case, you technically got yourself a range of objects that are cached and guaranteed to not change for the integer range -128 to 127, thus calling Integer.valueOf() upon these numbers would be perfect for your case.

Comment: Synchronizing on `Integer` instances is a very bad idea. If someone else has the same bad idea you end up having threads blocking each other for no good reason.

Comment: @Holger Yes I mentioned its quite hacky at the start. However, if all the code in the program is yours I don't see a problem... But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Even if it’s all yours one day you will forget what that single small routine of your application does internally and if you had chosen such a solution once you may pick up the same at some other point in the future. I think, every programmer had such a day when (s)he looked at some code and asked “Did I wrote that? Really?”